# Outlook 2013 is disconnected

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am using windows 8.1 64-bit. And Outlook 2013 on it. Yesterday it suddenly stopped sending emails. When I checked down there, it shows me 'Disconnected'. Clicking the Send/Receive button doing just nothing.

I am using Office 365 at the backend. I mean my email was created using Office 365 by my company, I guess.

P.S. I have checked working offline mode and then turning it back to the online mode but did not work.

[image]

Comment: If you "Control-Click" on the system tray icon you will get a longer menu than normal. One of the extra options will be "Connection Status", this will probably have something useful for getting a better answer than "reboot".

Comment: since this is related to office 365 you could get a faster response if you posted it on the office 365 community: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/default.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue of password reset. When I reset my password, it got connected.

Answer (score 2):

To have Outlook try to reconnect:

1. ctrl+click on the Outlook system tray icon
2. Connection Status
3. click Reconnect

Comment: I know the original poster already solved their issue, but there could be many reasons for this problem. So maybe this will help someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

When the session is disconnected, you will not be able to be access the send/receive option in the outlook. 
The possible solutions to get connected again are
1) Try logging into your system after one complete restart.
2) Also check your internet connections(if there any proxy applicable and also the VPN configurations).

Comment: 1. I have done a restart, and it did not work. 2. It was working fine since last 3 months but problem appeared yesterday. I am sure there's no issue of proxy etc.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot, [configure Outlook on a new mail profile](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-an-Outlook-profile-f544c1ba-3352-4b3b-be0b-8d42a540459d)

If this works without any issue, it would be an issue with your existing mail profile. Try [repairing your old mail profile](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Fix-your-Outlook-email-connection-by-repairing-your-profile-4d5febf6-7623-486b-9a9f-d5cfc4264af3)

If it still doesn't work, would need additional information to troubleshoot:

- Do other users in your organization have the same issue?
- Do you only have this issue when connecting from a specific network (i.e. at home, at office etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, then here's how truly re-install Office 365.

I tried many things, like different profiles, restore points, uninstalling Office 365 from the Control Panel, rebooting, re-installing. Nothing worked. Then it occurred to me that when you uninstall Office 365 is that what you REALLY do? If so, how come when I reinstalled it and clicked Outlook it just happened to remember I had 3 email addresses?

I then found Microsoft's official Office 365 uninstall tool:

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-Office-2013-or-Office-365-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8

I uninstalled using that (took around 15 minutes), rebooted, reinstalled from the link on the 365 account. This time when I clicked on Outlook I had to go through the process of setting up the email accounts. That suggested to me that some of the “hidden“ files left over from a “normal control panel” uninstall had gone this time.

I can report that after 4 days it's working as it should.

Comment: This is an answer to another question. The OP's issue was resolved by a password reset not a complete reinstall of Office.

Comment: @DavidPostill, assuming the answered also ran into a "Disconnected", then any answer that solves it seems fine to me, even if not applicable to the question asker. Future readers might need a full re-install if a password reset does not work for them?

Comment: @Arjan Then the answer should make clear he had the same symptoms. Suggesting a complete reinstall every time someone has a problem does not make for a good answer. And the answer misses out on suggesting "Office Repair" which should always be tried before a full reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of searchers, I tried creating a new profile and that didn't work. Bizarrely, this did:

- Close Outlook
- Disable all options in the Windows Firewall (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Firewall)
- Open Outlook (it connected)
- Re-enable the firewall
- Close and re-open Outlook. It now works.

I then opened and closed outlook several times to be sure. It definitely worked.

Obviously disabling firewalls is a risk, but for me it was a quick fix.